# How to inject dependencies into IClassFixture in XUnit?

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I am using XUnit and need to perform some action before running a test suit. so, I try to use IClassFixture feature of XUnit. but I cannot find a way to inject dependencies into the Fixture class. my code structure is such as below:

```
public class MyFixture
{
    IDependency _dep;

    public MyFixture(IDependency dep)
    {
        _dep = dep;
    }
    
    void DoSomeJob()
    {
       //// some code there
       dep.DoSome();
    } 
}
```

And this is my test class code:

```
public class MyTest : IClassFixture<MyFixture>
{
    [Fact]
    public void test_my_code()
    {
        ////simply just test the code
    }
}
```

but when I run the test I am getting the exception

> Xunit.Sdk.TestClassException Class fixture type 'MyFixture' had one or more unresolved constructor

Comment: Xunit doesn't do dependency injection like that. Why would it? I can't think of a valid reason to do this. Can you perhaps show a better (less contrived) example?

Comment: The goal of `IClassFixture` is to build those dependencies and share them by "injecting" instance of `IClassFixture` to the test class.

Comment: Try this xunit di support built into xunit framework: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xunit.Di/, so that you can inject services dependencies the same way as you do for any other applications.

Answer (score 2):

Your Fixture class depends on **IDependency dep**, which has not been configured. You could use the Fixture class to setup a service provider; However it is not the best solution, as you have to end up using service locator patter such as

```
serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>()
```

Suggest to use **xunit.di**, it is an extension built into xunit framework to support constructor dependency injection, which allows us to achieve Inversion of Control (IoC) between test classes and their dependencies.

```
Install-Package Xunit.Di
```

**To use xunit.di:**

- Install the xunit.di nuget package
- Create a Setup.cs class to configure dependencies, (optional) and inherits the Xunit.Di.Setup.cs
- Configure dependencies in the Setup.cs class.

Find full instructions and demos from [xunit.di GET-STARTED](https://github.com/clix455/Xunit.Di/blob/develop/GET-STARTED.md)

**Your test project has the following:**

- Setup class that has a public IServiceProvider, which configures all the dependencies
- Test class with constructor injecting the dependencies

Your **Setup.cs** class looks like below:

```
    private IServiceProvider _services;
    private bool _built = false;
    private readonly IHostBuilder _defaultBuilder;

    public Setup()
    {
        _defaultBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
    }

    public IServiceProvider Services => _services ?? Build();

    private IServiceProvider Build()
    {
        if (_built)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Build can only be called once.");
        _built = true;

        _defaultBuilder.ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
        {
            services.AddSingleton<TextReaderService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IDependency, DependencyImpl>();
            // where DependencyImpl implements IDependency
            // ... add other services needed
        });

        _services = _defaultBuilder.Build().Services;
        return _services;
    }
```

Then your test class looks like below:

```
public class MyTest
{
    private readonly IDependency _dependency;

    public MyTest(IDependency dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }

    [Fact]
    public void test_my_code()
    {
        var result = _dependency.DoStuff();
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        ////simply just test the code
    }
}
```